# Filtering with geokit rails - dosent show any data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, jbuilder, geokit

I am building an API for a webbapp using Ruby On Rails, i am using Jbuilder for API/JSON and Geokit.

I have this models:

**Campaign**

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
    belongs_to :venue
    belongs_to :category
    has_and_belongs_to_many :venues
    has_many :cities, through: :venues
    has_many :uses
end
```

**Company**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :venues
  has_many :campaigns
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

**Venue**

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base

    acts_as_mappable :default_units => :kms,
                     :lat_column_name => :lat,
                     :lng_column_name => :lng

    belongs_to :company
    belongs_to :city
    has_and_belongs_to_many :campaigns

end
```

I am trying to list all campaigns by given latitude and longitude coordinates, like this:

```
class API::CampaignsController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json

    def index
        @campaigns = filter
        respond_with @campaigns
    end
    def filter
        if params[:city_id]
            Campaign.includes(:venues, :cities).where('cities.id' => params[:city_id])
        elsif params[:lat] && params[:lng]
            lat = params[:lat].to_f
            lng = params[:lng].to_f
            Campaign.includes(:venues, :cities).within(10, :origin => [lat, lng])
        end
    end

end
```

But all I get is a empty hash:

```
{
campaigns: [ ]
}
```

Any ides on what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Comment: Can you share the server log generated for this action.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/shuma/9863919 @KirtiThorat

Answer (score 0):

As per the server log, `GET "/api/campaigns?lat=55.563466?lng=12.973509"`, you are not passing `params[:city_id]`  so your **BOTH** conditions in `filter` method will fail and no query would be executed. Hence, empty `campaigns`.

`acts_as_mappable` is on `Venue` model so `within` is available only for that model. I think you want `filter` method as below:

```
  def filter
    if params[:city_id]
      Campaign.includes(:venues, :cities).where('cities.id' => params[:city_id])
    elsif params[:lat] && params[:lng]
      lat = params[:lat].to_f
      lng = params[:lng].to_f
      Venue.within(10, :origin => [lat, lng]).includes(:campaigns, :city).each do |venue|
        campaigns << venue.campaigns  
      end
      campaigns
    end
  end
```

Also, the url should be `/api/campaigns?lat=55.563466&lng=12.973509`.

**NOTICE:**

Pass `lng` as a separate `query param` with `&` prefix as `&lng` and not as `?lng`

Comment: sorry it was a mistype from my side, but it still get an empty hash.

Comment: Update the gist with your server log again and let me know.

Comment: I see the problem. Can you share the view code that fires this request.

Comment: Not the index view. How do you reach the view: by `GET "/api/campaigns?lat=55.563466?lng=12.973509"` request. How is this request generated share that code.

Comment: the code is provide above, in the controller campaigns and the metod index.